# When I try to use multidimensional blocks or grids part of my resulted array occurs zeros

Tags: visual-studio, cuda

I slightly modify CUDA 10.1 Runtime project to acquaint with multidimensional blocks and grids. I use Visual Studio 2015 and NVIDA Quatro P400 video card. But in resulting array after some correct results follow zero values. What is wrong in following program? It uses meltidimensional blocks. The same is with grids.

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include <stdio.h>

cudaError_t addWithCuda(int *c, const int *a, const int *b, unsigned int size);

const int arraySize = 448 * 1024;
int a[arraySize];
int b[arraySize];
int c[arraySize] = { 0 };

__global__ void addKernel(int *c, const int *a, const int *b)
{
    int i =  256*(blockIdx.y*blockDim.x + threadIdx.y) + blockIdx.x*blockDim.x +  threadIdx.x;

    c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
}

int main()
{
    int     i;

    for(i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
    {
        a[i] = i;
        b[i] = i;
    }

    // Add vectors in parallel.
    cudaError_t cudaStatus = addWithCuda(c, a, b, arraySize);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "addWithCuda failed!");
        return 1;
    }

    // cudaDeviceReset must be called before exiting in order for profiling and
    // tracing tools such as Nsight and Visual Profiler to show complete traces.
    cudaStatus = cudaDeviceReset();
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaDeviceReset failed!");
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

// Helper function for using CUDA to add vectors in parallel.
cudaError_t addWithCuda(int *c, const int *a, const int *b, unsigned int size)
{
    int *dev_a = 0;
    int *dev_b = 0;
    int *dev_c = 0;

    dim3    threads(256, 4, 1);
    dim3    blocks(size >> 10, 1, 1);

    cudaError_t cudaStatus;

    // Choose which GPU to run on, change this on a multi-GPU system.
    cudaStatus = cudaSetDevice(0);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaSetDevice failed!  Do you have a CUDA-capable GPU installed?");
        goto Error;
    }

    // Allocate GPU buffers for three vectors (two input, one output)    .
    cudaStatus = cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_c, size * sizeof(int));
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMalloc failed!");
        goto Error;
    }

    cudaStatus = cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_a, size * sizeof(int));
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMalloc failed!");
        goto Error;
    }

    cudaStatus = cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_b, size * sizeof(int));
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMalloc failed!");
        goto Error;
    }

    // Copy input vectors from host memory to GPU buffers.
    cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(dev_a, a, size * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMemcpy failed!");
        goto Error;
    }

    cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(dev_b, b, size * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMemcpy failed!");
        goto Error;
    }

    // Launch a kernel on the GPU with one thread for each element.
    addKernel << < blocks, threads >> >(dev_c, dev_a, dev_b);

    // Check for any errors launching the kernel
    cudaStatus = cudaGetLastError();
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "addKernel launch failed: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(cudaStatus));
        goto Error;
    }
    
    // cudaDeviceSynchronize waits for the kernel to finish, and returns
    // any errors encountered during the launch.
    cudaStatus = cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaDeviceSynchronize returned error code %d after launching addKernel!\n", cudaStatus);
        goto Error;
    }

    // Copy output vector from GPU buffer to host memory.
    cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(c, dev_c, size * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMemcpy failed!");
        goto Error;
    }

Error:
    cudaFree(dev_c);
    cudaFree(dev_a);
    cudaFree(dev_b);
    
    return cudaStatus;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This calculation is incorrect:

```
int i =  256*(blockIdx.y*blockDim.x + threadIdx.y) + blockIdx.x*blockDim.x +  threadIdx.x;
```

I'm not sure how you came up with that.

The calculation should be to take your thread x index and add to it the grid width in x, times the row in y.

It should be:

```
int i =  (blockIdx.y*blockDim.y+threadIdx.y)*(gridDim.x*blockDim.x) + blockIdx.x*blockDim.x +  threadIdx.x;
//        the row in y                      * grid width in x       + thread index in x
```